# Word 2013 split document so you can view different parts at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I remember that in a older version of word there was a little square above the vertical scrollbar if you clicked it and dragged it down you would split the document in two that way you could look at the document in different places at the same time.

Does word 2013 have the same functionality and if where have they hidden it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this steps:

> 1. **Open** your Document.
> 2. Now click on the **View** toolbar.
> 3. And click on the **Split** button.
>
> [image: Split Screen]

Image is copied from [this](https://www.itsupportguides.com/office-2013/word-2013-how-to-split-window-and-view-two-sections-of-document-at-the-same-time/) site.

To turn off split, you can drag the bar to the top or click on the **Remove Split** button on the **View** toolbar.

Comment: This is available in other MS Office products as well as a lot of common apps, too

Comment: In future please blockquote **all** copied content. You are bordering on plagiarism with the way you are taking content from other sites. http://superuser.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

[Full Guide](https://www.itsupportguides.com/office-2013/word-2013-how-to-split-window-and-view-two-sections-of-document-at-the-same-time/)

They have removed the feature from the toolbar, but it hasn't been fully removed. The quick answer:

1. Open your document.
2. Click the view toolbar.
3. Click on split
4. It should then behave as in previous versions.

Comment: Your post was first and solved my problem but the other post is a tiny bit better and would help future readers of this page faster that's why i will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Completely understandable!